# A question on Inversion of a Permutation

Tags: probability

There is a defination of inversion their which states that the number of "inversions" of the word: the number of pairs of positions for which the leftmost position of the pair holds a letter 1 and the rightmost position holds a letter 0 in the word. For example, there is one word with 0 inversions, 0011. There is 1 with only a single inversion, 0101. There are two words with 2 inversions, 0110, and 1001. There is one with 3, 1010, and finally one word with 4 inversions, 1100.Could anyone what does this mean and i know what the inversion of a Permutation is but i did'nt get this defination.

Comment: Your title speaks of "permutations" but the examples you hold out are *words*, not permutations.  Are you confused about defining inversions in words, or about the distinction between words and permutations?

Answer (score 2):

For example, in $1010$ the inversions are the pairs $\{1,2\}$ (because the $1^{\text{st}}$ letter is $1$ and the $2^{\text{nd}}$ is $0$), $\{1,4\}$ (because the $1^{\text{st}}$ letter is $1$ and the $4^{\text{th}}$ is $0$), and $\{3,4\}$ (because the $3^{\text{rd}}$ letter is $1$ and the $4^{\text{th}}$ is $0$).

Comment: Thank you for your grateful response,could you tell me the source where you come through this so I could also reference.

Comment: I just know it. You could cite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics).